CA Code for Stair Railing Question
What’s typical for railing going downstairs in this situation? Can the railing stop right at the first step, at the 126” mark, or must go to the top landing?
The 126” is convenient since person doesn’t have to walk to landing to step down. (and it would look nicer)
What does California code say about this?


What's the point? You need a railing that goes all the way to the first step, and a newel post right at that corner.

Not going to the corner, while you say would be more convenient. would just make for a dangerous tripping hazard

@Cheery - there is a front door right in front of the staircase (going down) and having the extra space would allow for more area to move around. If the railing would be pushed back to the lip of the first step, would create the most amount of room...  As well as ability to start walking downstairs from the side of step...

@DJ. - would it pass code though? or nah?

Given that you don't meet the 36" width to meet code, why are you concerned about code for railings?

@Huesmann - existing stairs, we want to make sure its code for anything we are adding unto the home.

@PaulM If you modify the design,  you need to bring the whole stair up to current code.
